# ElasticSearch - Sorting not working

Tags: sorting, autocomplete, elasticsearch

Seems, I have an issue with sorting the results. Below is my config:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/companies -d '
{
  "settings" : {
     "analysis" : {
        "analyzer" : {
           "my_edge_ngram_analyzer" : {
              "tokenizer" : "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer"
            }
          },
         "tokenizer" : {
            "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                "type" : "edgeNGram",
                "min_gram" : "1",
                  "max_gram" : "5",
                    "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "company" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string" },
        "count" : {"type" : "long" },
        "name_suggest" : {
          "type" :     "completion",
          "index_analyzer": "my_edge_ngram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "my_edge_ngram_analyzer" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Here are examples to put into ES:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/companies/company/1 -d '
{
  "name" :         "1800flowers",
  "count": 1000,
  "name_suggest" : {
    "input" :      [
      "1800 flowers.Com, Inc",
      "1800 Flowers","1800-Flowers.com",
      "1 800 Flowers",
      "www.1800flowers.com",
      "1800Flowers.com", 
      "Inc,1-800-FLOWERS.COM",
      "1-800-FLOWERS.COM, INC",
      "1800Flowers",
      "1800Flowers Inc",
      "1800Flowers.com (Consultant)",
      "1-800-FLOWERS","1800Flowers.com",
      "1800FLOWERS INTERNATIONAL",
      "1-800 Flowers",
      "1-800 FLOWERS.COM, INC",
      "1-800-FLOWERS, Inc",
      "1800 flowers.com",
      "1-800Flowers.com",
      "1-800 flowers.com",
      "1800 Flowers Inc"
    ],
    "output" : "1800 Flowers"
  }
}'

curl -X PUT localhost:9200/companies/company/2 -d '
{
  "name" :         "1800 Ruby",
  "count": 10000,
  "name_suggest" : {
    "input" :      [
     "1800"
    ],
    "output" : "1800 Ruby"
  }
}'
```

Now clearly if I do a text search on 1800, I should get both of these objects back, giving output "1800 Flowers", "1800 Ruby".

Now really, I would like these results to be sorted by count, descending, so that I should have: "1800 Ruby", "1800 Flowers" but this isn't working!

```
curl -X POST localhost:9200/companies/_suggest -d '
{
  "query":{
  "companies" : {
    "text" : "18",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "name_suggest"
    }
  }
  },
  "sort": [ {"count": {"order": "desc"} } ]
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a weight in the in the `"name_suggest"` field of the docs. Also, you cannot use the `"query"` syntax in a `_suggest` request.

So, using the same settings and mapping you have above, I can update the docs with suggester weights equal to the `"count"`, as follows:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/companies/company/1" -d'
{
  "name" :         "1800flowers",
  "count": 1000,
  "name_suggest" : {
    "input" :      [
      "1800 flowers.Com, Inc",
      "1800 Flowers","1800-Flowers.com",
      "1 800 Flowers",
      "www.1800flowers.com",
      "1800Flowers.com", 
      "Inc,1-800-FLOWERS.COM",
      "1-800-FLOWERS.COM, INC",
      "1800Flowers",
      "1800Flowers Inc",
      "1800Flowers.com (Consultant)",
      "1-800-FLOWERS","1800Flowers.com",
      "1800FLOWERS INTERNATIONAL",
      "1-800 Flowers",
      "1-800 FLOWERS.COM, INC",
      "1-800-FLOWERS, Inc",
      "1800 flowers.com",
      "1-800Flowers.com",
      "1-800 flowers.com",
      "1800 Flowers Inc"
    ],
    "output" : "1800 Flowers",
    "weight" : 1000
  }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/companies/company/2" -d'
{
  "name" :         "1800 Ruby",
  "count": 10000,
  "name_suggest" : {
    "input" :      [
     "1800"
    ],
    "output" : "1800 Ruby",
    "weight" : 10000
  }
}'
```

And then a normal suggest request

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/companies/_suggest" -d'
{
   "companies": {
         "text": "18",
         "completion": {
            "field": "name_suggest"
         }
      }
}'
```

yields the expected results

```
{
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "companies": [
      {
         "text": "18",
         "offset": 0,
         "length": 2,
         "options": [
            {
               "text": "1800 Ruby",
               "score": 10000
            },
            {
               "text": "1800 Flowers",
               "score": 1000
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is a full runnable example: 
http://sense.qbox.io/gist/21cac07480e4077e083b037c5ac00016b04503f2

Comment: seems to work well. You know of a way to simply reference the count property rather than writing it twice?

Comment: Sadly no, I wasn't able to find one. One of the limitations of completion suggest, as far as I can tell.